# Deploying git archives with FTP

Tags: git, ftp

I'd like to deploy my git archive through an FTP connection to my webspace. As it's only a sharehoster I don't have root nor console access and obviously no git software. I set up like this:

```
git remote add deploy ftp://user:password@host
```

... and try to deploy like this:

```
git push deploy master
```

But I get: "Server denied you to change to the given directory".
I tried to create git's directories manually, but that didn't change anything. Has anyone a better advice than changing my hoster?

Comment: It sounds like you need to specify a path that you have write access to.

Comment: I have write access to the given directories in my FTP client, and the URL works in the browser. I tried the URL in git with and without a trailing slash, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send git data through FTP to a server. However, if you just want to deploy the worktree, the repo files that is, you can try something like [PHPloy](https://github.com/banago/PHPloy).

Disclaimer: I've created PHPloy.